# How to change the color of particular state on selection in google map

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm working on google maps api, 
I want to change color of multiple states on state selection in google maps.
something like this
[image: map]

I tried following code but it is coloring entire country.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'map_api_key'
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

        function drawRegionsMap() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['State', 'Popularity'],
            ['Maharashtra', 022],
            ['Goa', 19],
            ['Gujarat', 20]
       ]);

       var options = {};
       options['region'] = 'IN';
       options['colors'] = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']; //orange colors
       options['dataMode'] = 'markers';

       var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

       chart.draw(data, options);
   }
   </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it is coloring the India with blue color
[image: map]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, in order to display each "state", you will need the following option...

```
resolution: 'provinces'
```

next, the GeoChart uses colors differently from other google charts.
it uses a `ColorAxis`

> `colorAxis` - An object that specifies a mapping between color column values and colors on a gradient scale. To specify properties of this object, you can use object literal notation, as shown here:
>   `{maxValue: 1, minValue: 0,  colors: ['#FF0000', '#00FF00']}`

the color is calculated based on the row value from a mix of the colors provided.
in the example just stated,
the color for the row with the minimum value would be #FF0000
the color for the row with the maximum value would be #00FF00
remaining row colors would be a gradient somewhere between the two

in order to provide each state a unique color,
we will need to provide the values for each row,
along with the color

so in your example, we would need...

```
colorAxis: {
  colors: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
  values: [19, 20, 22]  // <-- colors must be in numerical order
},
```

note, each state you want to highlight will need to have a unique value.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Popularity'],
    ['Maharashtra', 22],
    ['Goa', 19],
    ['Gujarat', 20]
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'IN',
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
      values: [19, 20, 22]
    },
    dataMode: 'markers',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, [here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411362/5090771)...

Comment: Can we do it for City Level?

Comment: no, not with google's GeoChart. the only resolution smaller is for the USA only...

Comment: Any other map api to do this on city level?