# How to show regions as different color using Geo-charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have to display each region of Florida as a different color. I have used `geocharts` for the representation.

As we know, the state of Florida is divided into 6 regions (see below). Each region has counties. Each county has cities. Each city has communities.

[image]

I have tried the below code but nothing is reflected.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['geochart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['State', 'Passed Legislation'],
                ['FL-BAY', 1], ['FL-GULF', 0]
            ]);

    var options = {
        region: 'US-FL', // US
        colorAxis: {
            colors: ['#ffcccc', '#99ff66']
        },
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',

        datalessRegionColor: '#f2f2f2',
        defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    };
    options['resolution'] = 'provinces';

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

A Fiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/udcL0k3w/)

Could anybody let me know that how can I write BAY, GULF as data for the visualization?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411362/5090771) _might_ help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the KML layer, we can do the same.
I retrieved the individual city data from [source which has KML data](https://gadm.org/maps.html)

```
           var ctaLayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                url: 'https://rdmedialabs.com/PGT/assets/kml_layer.kml?1',
                map: map,
                clickable: false,
            });
```